# Stack Overflow Windows 7 Search Connector

Tags: search, windows-7

How do I write a Windows 7 Search Connector for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is with MSN as Google doesn't support RSS output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<OpenSearchDescription xmlns="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/" xmlns:ms-ose="http://schemas.microsoft.com/opensearchext/2009/">
    <ShortName>Stackoverflow.com</ShortName>
    <Description>Stackoverflow search with MSN</Description>
    <Url type="application/rss+xml" template="http://search.msn.com/results.aspx?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+{searchTerms}&amp;num=10&amp;format=rss"/>
    <Url type="text/html" template="http://search.msn.com/results.aspx?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+{searchTerms}"/>
</OpenSearchDescription>
```

Save the above as "Stackoverflow.osdx" and double click it.

Comment: This could work for tags, but for non-tag searches the provider needs a RSS feed. Guess search engine is the only one to provide RSS (without a key or user login) for searches!